# How to delete job pods once it will completed after retrying using backofflimit

Tags: kubernetes, hook, kubernetes-helm

In my case I have not added any parameter for backofflimit in kind:job
so job will retry for 6 times and if it is completed it will remove all pods Error and Completed as used hook delete policy.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: create-job
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": "post-install"
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": "hook-succeeded,before-hook-creation"
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "1"
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Never
      containers:
      - name: create-job
```

Problem Statement: This job is dependent on another Pod, So now that pod is taking time to come in running state.
So job runs for 6 times and not able to succeed, I have added backofflimit: 10, now the job reties 10 times and if it success in between then does not removed Error and Completed pods by default.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please reformat your question, it is not very readable right now? What it is the exact issue? What do you want to achieve? Did you do any research already? Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article.

Comment: @MikolajS. I want the solution how to retry jobs and once it is successful want to remove that error pods

Comment: Could you please make your [example reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Could you please share some logs, for example from the `kubectl describe job create-job` command?

Answer (score 1):

Your failed pod should be automatically deleted once hitting backofflimit (default to 6) if your restartPolicy is defined as onFailure.

In my case - cronjob defined and should run every 15mins:
[image]

All my job histories kept:
[image]

Describe the job - which tells it hit backoffLimit
[image]

The failed pod got deleted.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Check it out https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/74848